# How to Write HTML Special Characters without rendering them

Tags: html

This is probably an extremely simple question, but it's been bugging me for some time.

I'm trying to render user input `'&amp;'` as `'&amp;'`. The browser has been converting it to `'&'` for me, and I'm trying to figure out a way around it. This is happening for all encoded characters, not just the ampersand.

How do you render `'&amp;'` as text in HTML, rather than have it render as `'&'`?

Here is a JSFiddle -- http://jsfiddle.net/WSu6a/

Comment: Wrap in `<code></code>`?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. Is there some other thing I need to do to get <code> to work? Or that would make it not work?

Comment: The `code` markup has no effect on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

`<xmp>&amp;</xmp>`

It seems to work perfectly fine.

(Figured I'd come back and write a little bit about the `<xmp>` tag. Basically it's the deprecated version of `<pre>` that still is supported in browsers - Working version of the example: http://jsdo.it/haxxed/tmCT - [XMP Tag Details](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/_XMP.html))

Answer (score 5):

You can use `&#38;` or `&amp;` (ampersand) followed by the remainder of the code:

```
&#38;amp;
&amp;amp;
```

**Result**

&amp;

&amp;

Comment: You could just write `​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​&amp;amp;​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​` going that route. Couldn't you?

Comment: Then how you write &#38; without having it render?

Comment: @JonathanSampson Duh! Thanks :) Updated.

Comment: @streetlight If the code is `&amp;` then your HTML would be `&amp;` for the ampersand + the rest of the code (`amp;`) = `&amp;amp;`

Answer (score 2):

```
&amp;amp;
```

Also works fine.